# ng-repeat only outer elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have problem with ng-repeat in angularjs, what I want to achieve is to make ng-repeat'ed only outer elements in html, I'll introduce it in an example what I have and what I want to achieve.

I have example tabset like this :

```
      <tabset>
        <tab heading="{{tabs[0].title}}" active="tabs[0].active" disabled="tabs[0].disabled">
          <img ng-show="myPhotos" src="{{tabs[0].content}}" alt="FBphoto">
        </tab> 
        <tab heading="{{tabs[1].title}}" active="tabs[1].active" disabled="tabs[1].disabled">
          <a href="{{tabs[1].content}}"></a>
        </tab>
      </tabset>
```

What I want is to have tabset with ng-repeated  elements (to avoid array indexes in view) but with different elements inside, is it possible to smoothly achive it in angularjs ?

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
    <img ng-show="myPhotos" src="{{tab.content}}" alt="FBphoto"> <!-- Here I want to have various elements -->
</tab>
```

Comment: Directives would be great for this; when HTML elements are changing.

Comment: Do You think solution like : two directive with <img> and <a> templates + new variable in controller (saying which element I want to use for this data) passed do view can somehow solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then this is what you are looking for:

```
  <tabset ng-repeat="tabs in tabsetArray">
    <tab heading="{{tabs[0].title}}" active="tabs[0].active" disabled="tabs[0].disabled">
      <img ng-show="myPhotos" src="{{tabs[0].content}}" alt="FBphoto">
    </tab> 
    <tab heading="{{tabs[1].title}}" active="tabs[1].active" disabled="tabs[1].disabled">
      <a href="{{tabs[1].content}}"></a>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
```

And the model should be something like this:

```
$scope.tabsetArray = [ {'tabs': []}, {'tabs': []}, {'tabs': []} ... ];
```

you could also nest the `ng-repeat`

```
  <tabset ng-repeat="tabs in tabsetArray">
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
      <img ng-show="myPhotos" src="{{tab.content}}" alt="FBphoto">
    </tab> 
  </tabset>
```

EDIT: using `ng-switch`

```
<div ng-repeat="tabs in tabsetArray" ng-switch on="tab.title">
  <a  ng-switch-when="names" >do your thing here</a>
  <img  ng-switch-when="photos">
</div>
```

Comment: In fact this first solution still have array indexes inside html which  I want to avoid. Second solution have <img> tag inside, my problem is to dynamically add elements inside <tab> with proper tab.content values

Comment: So if there is something in `tab.content` then add an `<img>` tag otherwise do nothing. And if `tab.content` is an array with multiple elements then add multiple `<img>` tags?

Comment: nope, I have data like [{title:'photos',content:'linktophoto'},{title:'names',content:obj.with.names}] when title is photos I want <img> inside tab, in second case I want to create table inside it.

Comment: you can use `ng-switch` and the switch based on title, see the updated answer above and docs link: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

Comment: ng-switch would be nice to use, but I'm wondering if after using it there won't be too much duplicated html especially when there will be nested ng-repeat

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do further on but, just make directives for all those components. That keeps the html fairly clean.

Comment: I'll use directive as You said

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to use is `ng-bind-html-unsafe`, which allows you to directly include html tags into your scope variables - which will then get rendered properly on your templates. It would be something like..

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
    <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="tab.customElement"></div>        
</tab>
```

Then in your controller where you define the `tabs` data in `$scope` you'd have something like..

```
$scope.tabs = [
  {
    title : '',
    active : '',
    disabled : '',
    customeElement : '<a href="http://www.example.com">Test</a>'  
  },
  /*...other data..*/
];
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/HQpQH/) with a bare example of what I've explained above.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted ! Hovewer i need to ask if it is good practice to use it ?

Comment: yes, after all it is an Angularjs directive, see [here](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtmlUnsafe). Sorry should probably have included the link in the answer.

Comment: this solution is tempting but I don't want to modify DOM from my controller. I'll try to use directive instead. Thank You for Your help :)